# robots.txt access from localhost as well as external ips

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2, google-crawlers

I have used amazon cloud for hosting my website. For the last three month i got mails from amazon team that network traffic is high. After getting mail we are making our instances are more secure and clear the codes. While i am checking with this i can see see a post like [here](http://www.behind-the-enemy-lines.com/2012/04/google-attack-how-i-self-attacked.html) which saying that the google crawler may cause the attack. While i a checking the access log i can see that robots.txt has been access from bot localhost(127.0.0.1) and external ip. See the picture. [image]. Anyone can make me sure that this attach is due to google crawler or not?

Answer (score 0):

Google's crawler does not "attack," and it respects robots.txt if it fetches it. It can generate enough traffic to overload a poorly-written application, but it would never generate enough traffic for AWS to flag it and say "this isn't legitimate."  If you were experiencing what's discussed in the linked post, you wouldn't see it ask for robots.txt, because what's discussed there isn't a crawler.

One step to get you closer to knowing what's happening would be configuring apache to include the "User-Agent" in the log files.  The user agent string is a string that is supposed to be sent with every http request, to identify the browser or other web client.  It can be forged, so it is not something that can be fully trusted, but it provides useful high-level information.

Familiarize yourself with DNS concepts like nslookup, dig, and whois, which can be used in an attempt to identify the company controlling the IP address you see in each request.

The most troubling thing, here, is that you don't seem to know what is causing the requests from 127.0.0.1, which means something else *on your own server* is originating these requests.

If you are running a reverse-proxy or cache in front of apache, like haproxy or nginx or varnish or squid, this would happen, and the place you need to look is in the logs for the proxy, rather than apache.

It might be useful if you added some content to your question from the emails from Amazon that "traffic is high."  Amazon bills for traffic, so they don't typically mind if it's "high," but they do mind if it's *suspicious*.

Is the traffic inbound or outbound? What do you see in Cloudwatch monitoring for the instance's network usage?

Your server's security could have been breached through improper configuration or insecure coding practices... in which case, the traffic in question may not be web site traffic at all... and the security of everything in your application is at risk.

> we are making our instances are more secure

Well, depending on what you mean by that, it may not be enough.  Once an instance's security has been breached, the instance needs to be snapshotted if desired for forensic purposes, taken offline, and abandoned... you need to build new instances, with everything reinstalled from trusted sources, because you can never be assured that you've found everything.

This last advice, of course, is in no way AWS related... standard security best practices dictate that a compromised machine be wiped and rebuilt, rather than patched and cleaned up.